# incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'string' (aka 'char *') from 'int' [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c, string, cs50

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

string substitution(string k);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    //check dellla validità del numero di argomenti e della lunghezza della chiave
    if(argc == 1 || argc > 2 || strlen(argv[1]) < 26 || strlen(argv[1]) > 26)
    {
        printf("usage: ./substitution key (key more than 26 letters or more than 1 argument)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //check validità dei caratteri della chiave
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(argv[1][i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("only letters are allowed in the key\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }


    //alfabeto e array per contare i caratteri ripetuti
    int repeated[26];
    char alphabet[26] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

    //key è una string con i caratteri dell'argomento in minuscolo
    string key = argv[1];
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        key[i] = tolower(key[i]);
    }

    //controllare caratteri ripetuti nella string e aggiungere 1 a repeated[i]
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
        {
            if(alphabet[i] == key[j])
            {
                repeated[i]++;
            }
        }
    }

    //controllare se tutti gli elementi in key[] sono uguali a 1 altrimenti mandare un errore
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if(repeated[i] != 1)
        {
            printf("key must contain all of the alphabet withouth repeatitions\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }


    printf("ciphertext:%s\n", substitution(key));
}

string substituion(string k)
{
    k[26];
    char alphabet[26] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    char *ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)];

    //conversione da alfabeto ad alfabeto chiavato
    for(int i = 0; i <= strlen(plaintext); i++)
    {
        //MAIUSCOLO
        if(islower(plaintext[i]) == 0)
        {
            //se vede a quale lettera dell'alfabeto è plaintext[i] e si converte a k[j]
            for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
            {
                if(plaintext[i] == toupper(alphabet[j]))
                {

                    ciphertext[i] = toupper(k[j]);
                }
            }
        }
        //minuscolo
        else
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
            {
                if(plaintext[i] == alphabet[j])
                {
                    ciphertext[i] = k[j];
                }
            }
        }
    }


    return ciphertext;

}
```

I'm doing cs50's pset2, the substitution problem, and have been trying to solve it.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong but the error message has been the same for hours now.

The problem is clear, the only issue being that I can't assign character to the `ciphertext[i]` because the error message says that `k[j]` (or `toupper(k[j]`) for that matter) is an integer, which I'm sure it is not.  Also, what's a pointer?
P.S.
ignore the comments in italian :)

Comment: _or `toupper(k[j]`) for that matter) is an integer, which I'm sure it is not._ Sure about that? Better [double check](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/toupper.3.html) the return value.

Comment: Did you look at the man page for `toupper`?  If you did, you would immediately see that it returns an `int`.  The compiler was not wrong.  It is very unlikely that it would be for something like this.  The problem is you declared `ciphertext` to be an array of pointers, rather than an array of characters.  Do you see why that's a bug?  The compiler pointed you right at it.  If you change it to a character array, then you'll be assigning an `int` to a `char`, which is perfectly normal.

Comment: There are many other problems in this code.  For example, using `strlen` on a loop-invariant string in a loop test is a common beginner's mistake.  If you were doing it by hand, would you recompute the length every single time, even though you knew it hadn't changed?  Of course not.  Neither should properly-written code.

Comment: You're also trying to return a local array.  That's another severe bug.  All local variables go out of scope when a function returns.  If you try to return the address of one, you the caller will end up receiving a pointer into unallocated stack memory.

Comment: And of course, you never bothered to allocate, or set, a terminating null character for your result string.  So even if it were still in scope, it would still not be a valid null-terminated string.

Comment: @gondola, save time, enable all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 4):

`char *ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)];` is an array of `char *`, not an array of `char`.

`ciphertext[i] = toupper(k[j]);` is trying to convert the `int` return value of `toupper` into a pointer.

`return ciphertext;` is returning a pointer to the first element of a *local* array, which will no longer be valid when the function exits.

You will need to allocate the array in the calling function, or return a pointer to dynamically allocated memory:

Try using (with `#include <stdlib.h>`):

```
size_t length = strlen(plaintext);
char *ciphertext = malloc(1 + length);

if (!ciphertext)
{
    return NULL;
}

ciphertext[length] = '\0';
```

Note the additional element because to create a string you must *terminate* the array with the null character (`'\0'`).

And in `main`:

```
char *result = substitution(key);
if (result)
{
    printf("ciphertext:%s\n", result);
    free(result);
}
```

Alternatively, if dynamic memory is too unfamiliar, `plaintext` could be modified directly.

Additionally, the operator in the comparison used here:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= strlen(plaintext); i++)
```

should be `<`, not `<=`, and it would be best to use a stored result of calling `strlen`, instead of calling the function again at every step of the loop:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

---

`repeated[i]++;` is invoking [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior), as `repeated` was not initialized.

Use

```
int repeated[26] = { 0 };
```

to initialize all of its elements to zero.

---

A complete example program:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

string substitution(string k);

void usage(const char *progname)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s KEY\n\tKEY must contain exactly 26 non-repeating letters.\n", progname);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (2 != argc)
        usage(argv[0]);

    char *input = argv[1];
    size_t length = strlen(input);

    if (26 != length)
        usage(argv[0]);

    int counts[26] = { 0 };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        char as_lower = tolower((unsigned char) input[i]);

        if (!isalpha((unsigned char) input[i]) || counts[as_lower - 'a']++)
            usage(argv[0]);
        
        input[i] = as_lower;
    }

    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", substitution(input));
}

string substitution(string k)
{
    string str = get_string("plaintext: ");

    for (size_t i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char) str[i]))
        {
            str[i] = k[tolower((unsigned char) str[i]) - 'a'];
        } 
    }
    
    return str;
}
```

```
$ ./substitution VCHPRZGJNTLSKFBDQWAXEUYMOI
plaintext:  hello, world
ciphertext: jrssb, ybwsp
```

Answer (score 1):

this

```
char *ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)];
```

is your problem

you mean

```
 char ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)];
```

ie you want an array of characters. The first one asks for an array of pointers to characters

You also need space for the trailing \0 so you should do

```
 char ciphertext[strlen(plaintext) + 1];
```

Comment: *is your problem*?  Should probably be *is **a** problem* given the code...  ;-)